# fail2ban error with ssh-ddos Unable to read the filter 'sshd-ddos'

Tags: fail2ban

I am trying to get fail2ban working with ssh. I have changed the ssh port to `900` and have the following in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
port = 900
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
```

This works without any issues. However when I add an entry for `[sshd-ddos]`:

```
[sshd-ddos]
# This jail corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban.
# The mail-whois action send a notification e-mail with a whois request
# in the body.
enabled = true
port = 900
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
```

and run `sudo service fail2ban restart` and then check the status with `sudo systemctl status fail2ban` I can see there is an error:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-09-22 17:06:29 CST; 4s ago
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 7477 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7478 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/fail2ban (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7483 (fail2ban-server)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 1107)
   CGroup: /system.slice/fail2ban.service
           └─7483 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start

Sep 22 17:06:29 twitter-builder systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
Sep 22 17:06:29 twitter-builder systemd[1]: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
Sep 22 17:06:29 twitter-builder systemd[1]: Started Fail2Ban Service.
Sep 22 17:06:29 twitter-builder fail2ban-server[7483]:  Found no accessible config files for 'filter.d/sshd-ddos' under /etc/fail2ban
Sep 22 17:06:29 twitter-builder fail2ban-server[7483]:  Unable to read the filter 'sshd-ddos'
Sep 22 17:06:29 twitter-builder fail2ban-server[7483]:  Errors in jail 'sshd-ddos'. Skipping...
Sep 22 17:06:29 twitter-builder fail2ban-server[7483]: Server ready
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is your `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd-ddos.conf` file? Fail2ban is complaining because it is missing.

Comment: I guess I don't have one. Is there a typical config for this?

Comment: Well, you appear to have made it up, rather than trying to use one included with fail2ban, so you have to provide the filter.

Answer (score 4):

*[ssh-ddos]* jail [in fact is served by sshd.conf](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/02525d7b6f96c2841c24c4dbfcfe14e4a3d1ef63).

The solution is to add directive

```
filter = sshd
```

under
*[ssh-ddos]* section

Please note the comment under *[ssh-ddos]* directive that explains the difference:

> This jail corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban. The
> mail-whois action send a notification e-mail with a whois request in
> the body.

This solution worked for me.
Originally found [here](https://itgala.xyz/found-no-accessible-config-files-for-filter-d-sshd-ddos/)

Comment: Unfortunately there is a TYPING ERROR in the solution. Any beginner would be confused. This is the correct solution: Edit the file ```etc\fail2ban\jail.local``` and add a this line ```filter = sshd``` into this existing section: ```[sshd-ddos]``` Therefore this section could look like this: ```
[sshd-ddos]
enabled = true
filter = sshd
``` Please be more rigorous here. You are confusing the beginners by typing errors. You wrote ```[ssh-ddos]``` instead of ```[sshd-ddos]```

Comment: typo in the description aside, the recommended config change is correct and worked for me.